# Chaining two web service calls using RxJava and Retrofit

Tags: android, retrofit, rx-java

I am using RxJava and Retrofit.My basic requirement is,i want to chain two api calls, which will get called one after one another. Response received from first api is used as input while calling second api. After reading some stuff on internet i used to flatmap to achieve this. While carrying out this operation i am showing loader.Sometimes it runs smoothly but on some occasions this loader freezes. DDMS shows log of  "skipped 300 frames,Application may be doing too much work on its main thread". I suspect one of my network call is running on main thread. I am not able to figure out how to chain these two calls so that they can be smoothly called in background without hampering my main thread. Any help is greatly appreciated . Thanks in advance
This is what i have tried so far

```
private CompositeSubscription mSubscriptions = new CompositeSubscription();

Subscription subscription = Observable.just(getAddress())
          .subscribeOn(Schedulers.newThread())
          .flatMap(address -> mPlatformApi.secondWebService(address.getLatitude(),address.getLongitude())
          .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
          .subscribe(modelTwo ->
          {
            //updating My ui
          }, throwable -> {

            //Error Handling
          });

mSubscriptions.add(subscription);


private android.location.Address getAddress(){
    String addressString = "";//some Address String
    Geocoder coder = new Geocoder(getActivity());
    android.location.Address address=null;
    try {
      ArrayList<android.location.Address> addressList = (ArrayList<android.location.Address>) coder.getFromLocationName(addressString, 1);
      if(addressList !=null && addressList.size()>0) {
        address = addressList.get(0);
      } else {

      }
    } catch (IOException e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return address;
  }

//My Retrofit call
Observable<modelTwo> secondWebService(@Path("lat") double lat,@Path("lon") double lon);
```

Comment: It doesn't look like you are doing anything off the main thread. I would flat map the result of the first network call into the arguments for the second, then make the network call in your subscribe method. the code in your .subscribe() method is what is being executed off the main thread.

Comment: Is `getLatLonFromAddress` even used in your code anywhere? What is `doNetwokOperation` doing, how is it defined? Also, which Version of Retrofit are you using? Starting from 2.0-beta2, RxJava-style Retrofit calls are not automatically run on another thread anymore.

Comment: @ david.mihola I have edited the above code.all I meant by network operation was nothing but calling method 'getAddress()'. And I am using retrofit 1.9.

Comment: Ok, thanks! Still, there must be something wrong with the example: `getAddress` does not return an `Observable`, yet you call `subscribeOn` on it... That should not even compile...

Comment: @david.mihola i was using Observable.just(getAddress()). i will edit the code again. Really sorry for inconvenience

Comment: @david.mihola. My basic confusion is ,can i use flat map if i want to chain two api's ?am i doing in correct way? if not, is there any better solution to achieve this.

Comment: No worries! But that explains the problem - I just need to get the laptop out to write a proper answer...

Comment: @david.mihola Thanks a lot. take your time. I will wait

Comment: Ok, answered - there was a mistake in my answer when I first posted it. Of course, it must be `defer` and not `just`!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Consider this:

```
final android.location.Address address = getAddress();
Subscription subscription = Observable.just(address) ...
```

This is equivalent to your code, but should also make it clear that `getAddress()` is evaluated *before RxJava is involved and has had any chance to intervene*. In other words, when you use `just`, the `subscribeOn` can only move the *emission* of the Address (calling `onNext(address)` on your `Subscriber`) to another thread. However, the *creation* of the Address - that is, your `getAddress` - will already have happened on the main thread when you get to this point.

The easiest way to actually move `getAddress` to another thread is to use `defer`:

```
Subscription subscription = Observable.defer(new
          Func0<Observable<android.location.Address>>() {

              @Override
              public Observable<android.location.Address> call() {
                  return Observable.just(getAddress());
              }
          })
          .subscribeOn(Schedulers.newThread())
          .flatMap(address -> mPlatformApi.secondWebService(address.getLatitude(),address.getLongitude()    )
          .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
          .subscribe(modelTwo ->
          {
            //updating My ui
          }, throwable -> {
            //Error Handling
          });
```

This way, the whole `Func0` will be executed on `newThread()` - not only the `just` but also the `getAddress`.

Comment: Great answer. i had some idea that Observable.just() runs on main thread. but i had no idea about this Observable.defer().  This definitely solves this use case

Comment: I have one more use case to discuss with you. Here i was flat mapping response of getAddress() into second retrofit call.But suppose i want to chain two retrofit  calls . i.e. flat mapping the result of first retrofit call into second one. in this case as well should i be using Observabe.defer()?

Comment: No, in that case you can just the `Observable` that Retrofit returns. Before 2.0-beta2 it will already be running off the main thread and you can put the `flatMap` right after it. From 2.0-beta2 forward it will by default be run on the thread you are creating it on - but it will be constructed in such a way that calling `subscribeOn` will move the actual network communication (and probably any JSON parsing, etc.) to another thread.