# Android: RxJava with OkHttp: How to make second call which is dependent on first?

Tags: android, rx-java, okhttp

**I'm not using Retrofit.**
 I have to make the first call to get an auth cookie, then  I need to make a second call with the same OkHttclient client (actually I'm assuming I need the same client because of the auth cookie) . So when the first http call is completed I then need to make another call to another url using the same client variable. How can I achieve this cleanly?

I thought that I could use .concatWith (see in the code below) but I'm not sure if thats correct as I could not find any solid examples.

```
 Subscription subscription =   Observable.create(new Observable.OnSubscribe<Response>() {

                    OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient.Builder()
                    .cookieJar(new CookieJar() {
                        private final HashMap<HttpUrl, List<Cookie>> cookieStore = new HashMap<>();

                        @Override
                        public void saveFromResponse(HttpUrl url, List<Cookie> cookies) {
                            cookieStore.put(url, cookies);
                        }

                        @Override
                        public List<Cookie> loadForRequest(HttpUrl url) {
                            List<Cookie> cookies = cookieStore.get(url);
                            return cookies != null ? cookies : new ArrayList<Cookie>();
                        }
                    })
                    .build();


                    @Override
                    public void call(Subscriber<? super Response> subscriber) {
                        try {
                            HttpUrl.Builder urlBuilder = HttpUrl.parse(AUTHTOKEN_URL).newBuilder();
                            urlBuilder.addQueryParameter("username", AUTHTOKEN_USERNAME);
                            urlBuilder.addQueryParameter("password", AUTHTOKEN_PASSWORD);
                            String url = urlBuilder.build().toString();

                            Request request = new Request.Builder()
                                    .url(url)
                                    .build();

                            Response response = client.newCall(request).execute();

                            subscriber.onNext(response);
                            subscriber.onCompleted();

                            if (!response.isSuccessful()){
                                subscriber.onError(new Exception("error"));
                            }

                        }
                        catch (IOException e) {
                            subscriber.onError(e);
                        }
                    }
                })
                .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
                .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
                .concatWith(

                    //what code goes here??
                )
                .subscribe(new Subscriber<Response>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onCompleted() {

                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onError(Throwable e) {

                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onNext(Response response) {

                    }
                });

                return subscription;
    }
```

Comment: Not sure if this is the best or most elegant "RXJava way" but....I just ended up running another  client.newCall(request).execute();  after the first one in the same code block.

Comment: see below  [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/40880933/3629732)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Chaining two web service calls using RxJava and Retrofit](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33736775/chaining-two-web-service-calls-using-rxjava-and-retrofit)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See the code RxJava Way

```
    //Create your customized OkHttpClient
  final OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient.Builder()
            .cookieJar(new CookieJar() {
                private final HashMap<HttpUrl, List<Cookie>> cookieStore = new HashMap<>();

                @Override
                public void saveFromResponse(HttpUrl url, List<Cookie> cookies) {
                    cookieStore.put(url, cookies);
                }

                @Override
                public List<Cookie> loadForRequest(HttpUrl url) {
                    List<Cookie> cookies = cookieStore.get(url);
                    return cookies != null ? cookies : new ArrayList<Cookie>();
                }
            })
            .build();


    Observable<AuthResponse> authObservable = Observable.fromCallable(new Func0<AuthResponse>() {
        @Override
        public AuthResponse call() {
            return doOkHttpAuthOperation(client);//You can do with your auth cookie and Login Credentials
        }
    });

    Observable<NormalResponse> normalObservable = authObservable.map(new Func1<AuthResponse, NormalResponse>() {
        @Override
        public NormalResponse call(AuthResponse authResponse) {
            return doOkHttpNormalOperation(client);//Normal API call
        }
    });


    Subscription subscription = normalObservable.subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
            .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
            .subscribe(new Subscriber<NormalResponse>() {
                @Override
                public void onCompleted() {

                }

                @Override
                public void onError(Throwable e) {
                    //if Any Error occurred
                }

                @Override
                public void onNext(NormalResponse normalResponse) {
                    //Authenticated Response
                }
            });
```