# Retrofit2/Android - call multiple webservices in a chain

Tags: java, android, retrofit2

I'm  new with Retrofit. My current solution is to call first webservice and in OnResponse override, call second one, providing result from first call as parameter to second call.
Finally, I need an object containing data loaded from both webservices called. My solution actually works. However, I'm not satisfied with it. Code is not clean and terrible to maintain (I will also need 3 webservices chain).

I've heard something about RxJava and flatMap method. Can anybody point me right direction? Complete code sample/turorial (including Retrofit intrerfaces definition) would be very helpful. Partial code samples I have already found is not something easy to understand, so I'm stuck now.

Thanks and sorry for possible duplicate.

Comment: Doesn't googling "rxjava retrofit multiple calls" help you in any ways"

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33736775/chaining-two-web-service-calls-using-rxjava-and-retrofit. yup there are lots of similar questions on stackoverflow

Comment: Don't get me wrong, I'm looking for some complete sample, most questions on stackoverflow don't include (for example) Retrofit interface definitions (as I already know, they must be slightly different for rxJava).